# How can I test a User Control without adding to an ASPX file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, testing, user-controls, asp.net-3.5

Currently if I want to test a user control, I add my custom tags into an existing .aspx page (or create a new one if I have to), and then view this page in the browser.

Is there a quicker, better way to test User Controls which I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run a user control like you would a page. You could create a simple test form for testing it...